# Hub transport rule with Exchange 2010: working with empty values?

Tags: exchange-2010

We use a hub transport rule to automatically append a corporate signature to all outbound emails.

Certain values are pulled from staff AD profiles and imported into the appropriate section of dynamic signatures when emails are sent. This works perfectly for us at the moment but I am running into an issue when trying to add an extra value which, unlike the phone numbers already in the dynamic signature, does not apply to everyone (mobile numbers).

Up until now, we have included two phone numbers in signatures: the office number (preceded by a "p." prefix) and fax number (preceded with a "f." prefix). These numbers existed for absolutely everyone in AD - so there was no issue with blank AD fields leaving a prefix that was not followed by a value.

Now, if I add "mobile" as an additional field in our corporate signature, any users who do not have a mobile phone are left with the prefix "m." (*example below*)

*John Doe
p. 123-456-7890 f. 123-456-7890 **m.***

Is there any way that I can make our hub transport rule smart enough that it does not include a particular prefix if there is no corresponding AD value for a given user?

Answer (score 1):

When appending text to a message, a hub transport rule performs a simple variable substitution; it isn't a text preprocessor, and it has no complex logic such as "insert this text only if this value exists".

However, the rule itself *can* have this kind of logic; so you could build two rules: one that appends text including the mobile phone number if the corresponding AD attribute exists, and another one which appends the same text but without the mobile phone number if the AD attribute is empty.

Comment: I'm trying to find the logic you describe but am having some trouble. The only condition related to AD is, "If the sender and recipient's AD attribute are Evaluation" but that doesn't really apply to our situation. We aren't concerned with *recipient* AD attributes (many recipients will be external anyway) - just whether or not the sender has a value for their "mobile" AD attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: See predicates 35 and 36 here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638183(v=exchg.141).aspx.

Comment: I seem to have a choice of "When the Subject field contains specific words" and "When the Subject field matches text patterns". What could I use as a wildcard to detect *any* data in the "mobile" AD field (not just data which conforms to a certain format)?

Comment: I don't know and I don't have an Exchange server available to test it... but it shouldn't be that difficult to create a text pattern that matches any value and doesn't match an empty attribute.

Comment: Just to correct my last comment: the two applicable options for this relate to the sender's (AD) properties, not the contents of the Subject field. 1) "When the sender's properties contain specific words" or 2) "When the sender's properties match text patterns".